# Having problems with saving and loading in Swift 3.0 iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, crash, save, load

I'm really new to the Swift and iOS programming scene and I am trying to learn a bunch of things. For this app, I want to save and load just one integer, but I am having problems, as everything I found on stack overflow and the Internet just doesn't seem to work on Swift 3. The app crashes immediately, it breaks on:

```
@IBOutlet weak var StaticLabel: UILabel!
```

It says "Thread 1: breakpoint 3.5" . Any help and tips would be very much appreciated :)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var player: AVAudioPlayer?
var number = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var StaticLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var NumberLabel: UILabel!
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Load()
    }

    func Load()
    {
        number = defaults.integer(forKey: "Save")
        NumberLabel.text = String(number)
    }

    func playSound()
    {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "RightYouAre.mp3", ofType: nil)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        do {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player = sound
            sound.play()
        }
        catch {
            // couldn't load file :(
        }

    }


    @IBAction func Minus(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        number = number - 1
        NumberLabel.text = String(number)
        defaults.set(number, forKey: "Save")
    }

    @IBAction func Plus(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playSound()
        number = number + 1
        NumberLabel.text = String(number)
        defaults.set(number, forKey: "Save")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to update your question (do not post a comment) with details about the crash. What is the complete error message? Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: Also see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: Your code does not show any usage of the StaticLabel at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your line of code

```
number = defaults.integer(forKey: "Save")
```

user defaults integer for key Save is nil, actually this key does not exist at all in the user defaults

before you load this integer from user defaults , it has to be set first

```
 if defaults.object(forKey: "Save") !=    nil { number =    defaults.integer(forKey: "Save") }
```

this will make sure the object exists in the user defaults before getting it's value

finally your load function should be

```
func Load() 
{
    if defaults.object(forKey: "Save") != nil 
    { 
        number = defaults.integer(forKey: "Save") 
        NumberLabel.text = String(number)
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add null handling to the load function as first time there
>   will be no value for the key `"save"` in your UserDefaults.

```
func Load()
{
    if let number = defaults.integer(forKey: "Save")
    {
        self.number = number
        NumberLabel.text = String(number)
    }
}
```

Comment: Managed to fix it! Thanks :)

Comment: was it the same problem

Comment: I think it was the same one

Comment: almost same but it's not the correct way to add null handling in swift